# Автоматизация обновлений IIS site, Windows Service, Jobs

Tags: администрирование, автоматизация

Для автоматизации обновлений сайтов IIS, Windows Service, Jobs и накатывание sql скриптов, необходима единая система управления, на сколько мне известно для Linux есть Ansible.

Сейчас автоматизация раскинута на разных серверах скриптами PowerShell.

Какие системы можно использовать чтобы собрать всю автоматизацию в одном месте и в удобном виде?
Есть ли аналоги Ansible для Windows или он способен решать указанный круг задач?

Comment: Ты тег "авторизация" с "автоматизацией" не перепутал случаем?

Comment: Ошибся к сожалению

Answer (score 0):

1. У самого ansible достаточно [большое](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/list_of_windows_modules.html) количество модулей для управления Windows.
2. Отдельно стоит упомянуть обёртку для [DSC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dsc/overview/overview). Называется (кто бы мог подумать) [win_dsc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_dsc_module.html). DSC - это тот же ансибл, только на винде, для винды и от винды. Существует параллельно с `AD\GPO`.
3. Никто не мешает заюзать прямое дёргание `powershell` на конечной машине через [win_command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_command_module.html#win-command-module) и прикручиванием [идемпотентности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) руками.